# How to use As in IF condition of mysql query?

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I am working on ledger and my php code require query to identify whether its debit amount OR credit amount.

```
SELECT jobber, 
IF(Pay_type='Payable', amount AS credit_amount, amount AS debit_amount)
 FROM Jobber_payments
```

I have also tried this but not working for me. If there is any possibility in above query.

```
SELECT jobber, IF(Pay_type='Payable', credit_amount, debit_amount) AS amount_type
amount AS (SELECT amount_type)
FROM Jobber_payments
```

if condition(Pay_type='Payable') is true, it will pass

credit_amount will be a field name or column name and amount value 5000

else
debit_amount will be a field name or column  name and amount value 5000

Comment: Not clear.  Please include the exact output you want to see here.

Comment: With the alias you give a name for the 2nd column of your query. Eachcolumn can have only 1 name. What you are trying to do is give different names to this 2nd column for each row which is not allowed.

Comment: Then how to deal with it, any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a column with 2 different names (aliases). 
What you can do is have 2 columns, one for every case:

```
SELECT 
  jobber, 
  case when Pay_type='Payable' then amount end AS credit_amount, 
  case when Pay_type<>'Payable' then amount end AS debit_amount 
FROM Jobber_payments
```

In this case there are 2 columns, one of which will be null and the other will contain a value.

Comment: my code accept only credit_amount or demit_amount not both :(

Comment: Then you leave it as it is: 1 column with name `amount` and distinguish by the type.

Answer (score -2):

The IF condition is explained in details below;

```
IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

Check the link below they have explained the use of IF clearly.

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp